# Looking for an a icon dropdown add-on?

Tags: add-on, add-on-development

Did anybody ever make an add-on that has a icon dropdown (select dropdown)?

Something like this: 
http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown
Where you can add icons. Preferrably svg with a png fallback. But since it's only Backend, it can be png only.

I am also open to found this!

cheers
stefan

Comment: Do you mean as a fieldtype? Or something for the frontend?

Comment: ah - I meant is as a fieldtype... to let the user choose something with either an image or a logo.

Answer (score 2):

No. Create your own using Grid or Matrix fieldtype. Define the values in a select dropdown, then in your template code have each value correlate to a specific icon with conditionals.

Comment: That's exactly how I do it!